# Packing a rectangle with equal sized circles python

Tags: python

I have a rectangular bounding box defined by width `w` and height `h` and area `A`.

How can we pack `n` number of circles of equal area `a` inside this rectangle such that `A-n*a` is minimal.

In other words, how can we calculate the optimal number of equal sized circles that can be packed inside a rectangle

**My use case:**
I am using kmeans clustering algorithm for clustering vehicles in a geographical bounding box. In order to set the number of clusters for the kmeans algorithm, I am experimenting with circle packing as one way of deriving the number of clusters before I apply the kmeans algorithm.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square

Comment: Add your use case and the kmeans tag so you might get some super cool methods of deciding on optimal number of clusters from others. See this as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Edited to help the OP get a number that can help in deciding the number of k-means clusters based on fitting circles in a plane and minimizing the uncovered places.

```
from math import sqrt, pi

def get_approximate_k(rectangle_area, circle_area):
    # Making use of the fact that in an infinite hexagonal packing, the packing ratio is (pi*sqrt(3)/6)
    return int((rectangle_area * pi * sqrt(3))/(6 * circle_area))

print get_approximate_k(10*100, 12) # Returns 75
```

Comment: Hexagonal packing is not always optimal. See the wikipedia links I posted above.

Comment: I am using kmeans clustering algorithm for clustering vehicles in a geographical bounding box. In order to set the number of clusters for the kmeans algorithm, I am experimenting with circle packing as one way of deriving the number of clusters before I apply the kmeans algorithm

Comment: @tobias_k, you are right. But in general, where the box size is huge w.r.t to the ball size, more often than not, hexagonal packing would do the trick. At least that is what I have been believing in since I studied molecule packing in solids some years ago!

Comment: In the link you shared, the area of the circles is fixed. IN our case, we are free to choose any area that mimimizes the difference between the area of the rectangle and the sum of areas of the circles

Comment: @Mechanic, I see. I am assuming you also don't want to leave out any vehicle?

Comment: @srey123: Exactly, I needed a 2D solution not a 3D one.

Comment: @Mechanic, as per your use case, you must be considering overlapping circles that could cover the entire plane, isn't it?

Comment: @srey123: not overlapping circles. once I have the number of non-overlapping circles, I can give it as an input to the kmeans algorithm that takes care to also cluster the vehicles left out in the empty spaces.

Comment: @Mechanic, cool. Got it. I thought you wanted to force the kmeans clustering to cover everything as circles all over the place. You can use the hexagonal packing method for it.

Comment: I have searched in the internet and found no useful links. Any advise on how to proceed with that in python?

Comment: Added a function that can give you the number of circles that can fit. To get the area of the circle that minimizes the area difference - the answer would be almost 0 - as that is where the area difference would be 0. My suggestion would be to choose an area that gives you good clustering.